# Scrapy : Use selector (xpath) in ItemLoader 's output processor

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I don't know how to make my logic works in my case.

I want to extract row from a table from which I don't know in advance the number of columns. 
Here is the source :

```html
<article class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">

  <b>Quantités recommandées (g/jour)  :</b><br>
  <br>
  <table border="1" width="80%">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="2*">
      <col width="1*">
      <col width="1*">
      <col width="1*">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small><b>Poids du chat</b></small></td>
        <td align="center"><small><b>Maigre</b></small></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>2 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>39 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>3 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>52 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>4 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>63 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>5 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>74 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>6 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>84 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>7 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>94 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>8 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>103 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>9 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>112 g</small></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><small>10 kg</small></td>
        <td align="center"><small>121 g</small></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</article>
```

To extract I hardcoded this :

```
feeding_box_table=response.xpath('//*[@id="feedingrecommendation-panel"]/div/article/table')
        feeding_recommendation=[]
        if feeding_box_table!=[]:
            for tr in feeding_box_table.xpath("tr"):
                tds=tr.xpath('td/small/b/text()|td/small/text()').extract()
                feeding_recommendation.append(tds)
```

However when I want to implement this hard-coded solution with item loader it gets tricky because I can iterate in `feeding_box_table.xpath("tr")`since the value collected in the out_processor is a `str`and not an object where `xpath`is collected.

I don't know if processors should be use that way actually. That's why I tried to do everything with xpat like : `table=response.xpath('//*[@id="feedingrecommendation-panel"]/div/article/table/td/small/text()') but the output is not structured.`

The output wasn't satisfying as it was : 
Output : `["Poids du chat","Maigre","2 kg","39 g",...."10 kg", "121 g"]`

That's the reason why I wanted to iterate through `<tr></tr>`

Desired Output : `[["Poids du chat","Maigre"],["2 kg","39 g"],....["10 kg", "121 g"]]`

Any help appreciated. 
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this :

```
feeding_recommendation=[]
for tr in response.xpath('//*[@id="feedingrecommendation-panel"]/div/article/table/tr|//*[@id="feedingrecommendation-panel"]/div/article/table/tbody/tr'):
    tds=tr.xpath('td/small/b/text()|td/small/text()').extract()
    feeding_recommendation.append(tds)

l.add_value('feeding_recommendations_table',feeding_recommendation)
```

It does work. But I'm really not sure that I'm making the most out of ItemLoader here.